# Bash: while, read and more together

Tags: bash

When using a combination of the while, read and more commands in a bash script, I received some output that should not be printed.

The minimal example consists of a shell script 'problem.sh' and two test files 'test.dat' and 'test2.dat':

### problem.sh:

```
while read row; do
  #echo $row
  more test2.dat
  echo HERE
done < test.dat
```

### test.dat:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

### test2.dat

```
lefttop
abc
leftbot
```

The program is supposed to print three times the three rows of *test2.dat* in the terminal (number of while loop runs checked with **echo HERE**), however it gives out also **test2** and **test3** of *test.dat* at the beginning of the program execution (even if **echo $row** is commented out as above, else it additionally prints **test1** at the beginning) and only runs once through the loop. Any help?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, but it looks like `more` is reading from both test2.dat *and* its standard input, which it inherits from the while loop. Does changing the `more` command to `more test2.dat < /dev/null` help? (As an aside, you should use `cat` instead of `more` if are only interested in displaying the contents of the file, not paging through it.)

Comment: @chepner You are right. Using /dev/null prevents it from taking input of while but still the format looks odd. Using cat instead of more prints it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Indeed all of your suggestions work. I knew that the script runs fine with cat :), as I tried replacing more with it before I posted the question (out of curiosity why this is only happening when more is used btw).

Comment: re: why this only happens when `more` is used -- because the expected use case for `more` involve reading from the user to be able to display additional content only when they ask for it by pressing enter or space. If your implementations reads from the user via stdin when given filenames on its argument list... well, there you are; the content on stdin is `test.dat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `test.dat` away from stdin to FD 3, letting `more` use stdin uninterrupted:

```
while read -r row <&3; do
  #echo $row
  more test2.dat
  echo HERE
done 3< test.dat
```

That's assuming, of course that you *want* `more` to be able to interact with the user. If you just want to concatenate files together, use `cat` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `more test2.dat` by `more test2.dat < /dev/null` to stop more reading from stdin (test.dat), too.

Comment: Depending on your implementation of `more`, this may prevent it from being able to get a TTY handle to interact with the user.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I could reproduce the problem and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, *for one specific version of `more`*. There's more than a single implementation.

Comment: Related: When using this fix, does `more` still serve as a pager when handling large files? (If it doesn't fall back to `/dev/tty`, it may not -- again, dependent on the specific implementation).